# OpenJPA joined inheritance - avoid database joins

Tags: inheritance, jpa, discriminator

I'm using OpenJPA with Joined inheritance strategy (InheritanceType.JOINED - so there is a single table for all the fields in the superclass, and subclass tables just include fields for anything that is added in the subclass, plus a reference back to the superclass table). 
Let's say I have a superclass Person, and a number of subclasses: TypeAPerson, TypeBPerson etc. When having a query such as:

```
@NamedQuery(
name="Person.findByName", 
query="SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.name = :name")
```

as far as I'm familiar, I will not get a Person instance but the proper subclass instance.
As stated [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html#jpa_overview_mapping_inher_joined_disadv) , in order to achieve this and to get the proper subclass, OpenJPA will make multiple joins (one for each subclass). This has quite bad performance, especially if I have a lot of subclasses.
My question is if there is any way to avoid this by giving JPA a hint which table to join? First thing that comes to my mind is using Discriminator value. OpenJPA supports having Discriminator with Joined strategy, so it should be able to determine a subclass (and thus a proper table for joining) from discriminator value? Is there an way to achieve this?
Is there some other way to avoid unnecessary database joins?

Comment: I am not an expert, but DiscriminatorColumn could be the solution. Check out a complete example with Joined Inheritance and DiscriminatorColumn usage [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

If you need only entities of a single subclass, then the best way to avoid superfluous joins  is to query for this subclass. Using your example, it could look like this:

```
@NamedQuery(
name="Student.findByName", 
query="SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.name = :name")
```

`Student` is a subclass of `Person`. Of course, the named query should be defined on the appropriate subclass.

There is no way to have it both ways - using a superclass query and joining only a single subclass table. The persistence provider does not know about the results beforehand and the only way to hint in the right direction is to search for the subclass.

**EDIT:** If you are not sure about the exact subclass, but can limit the possible sublasses, you could use the JPQL `TYPE` keyword with an IN clause, like this:

```
queryString="SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.name = :name AND TYPE(p) IN (Student, Teacher)"
```

Use the entity name as parameter for the `TYPE`. AFAIK, it is case sensitive. The actual discriminator type and value are not important, since you are not querying for it. The type resolution is done by the provider.

I am not sure however, whether it will enable the provider to limit the necessary joins. If you end up using or benchmarking it, please tell if it does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This option is unfortunately not suitable for my case. I have a situation where I know Person.Id, but I don't know its type in advance so I cannot query for a specific subclass. That's why I asked about discriminator - the only approach that I can think of now is making two queries: selecting a Person, and then based on discriminator value, query for the proper subclass. But it seems strange that this is not supported by JPA since discriminator is used to resolve subclass.

Comment: @Ane - I see. There is a different possibility that I have not thought of earlier, using the TYPE keyword. Please see the edit.